# How do I move my div upp with css to center it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdownlist and some divs in circle shape: see here

[image]

How can I move the circle up just a little bit in order to center it with my dropdownlist?

I have tried:

```
 #circles{
 
    display: inline-block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 70%; 


}
```

Comment: please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: try `vertical-align: middle;` for `#circles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using top / margin-top properties of css.

```
#circles{
    display: inline-block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 70%; 
    top: someValue px;
}
```

or

```
 #circles{
    display: inline-block; 
    float: left; 
    width: 70%; 
    margin-top: someValue px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap everything with an other div and give it

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put them all in one container and set the following

```
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```